# How to add Google Play support in Anbox?

Tags: google, adb, anbox

I know it's a relatively new and unstable application but I figured if anyone has suffered through the issue and solved it then they can help me too.

Anbox does't come with Google Services, As Google Services can't be installed on an Unregistered Device / Firmware, but their are ways to achieve that in Custom Roms or even Emulators, But if you want to use Android to it's fullest then Google Play Services is a must.

**What have I tried so far?**

I've tried to install Google Play Services x86 apk, which successfully got installed and also appears in Settings > Apps

I've Also tried to install Play Store which also got successfully installed and appear in the App Drawer of Anbox (also In Gnome).

But it Doesn't work like Expected, for example, YouTube app loads content but can't play videos, Google play store doesn't even load content, I think maybe because Google Play Services isn't installed as System app/ or maybe because there are some other g-apps that these things depend on and i'm missing them.

I'm ready to provide more details from my side

Comment: This is off-topic any way you look at it.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I figured Anbox is an Linux app and i'm Running it from Ubuntu, Where else can i ask it?

Comment: The way I see it, it's like asking how to install some package on a CentOS container running in Ubuntu. Doesn't matter that it's running on Ubuntu, since the problem is entirely inside the container.

Comment: @muru is see that now,  I've asked the question on Android Enthusiasts, should I delete it from here?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh care to put the link of the question on Android Enthusiasts?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/172965/how-to-add-google-play-support-in-anbox here you go

Comment: The way I see it, its like asking about virtual-box, which is also off topic but totally entertained on this site.

Comment: @j0h I genuinely thought that this could benefit me as well as other people because this snap package is almost exclusively available on Ubuntu, for other distors it gives a message like  "not correct distro" or something.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh I think it could too. When I figure out the answer, I'll post it.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this would be off-topic. In particular, I expect that if Google Play can be run in Anbox then it will be side-loaded using `adb` or a similar tool running in the Ubuntu system. I'm voting to reopen this.

Comment: @EliahKagan a) You can SSH to a Debian container running in Ubuntu, that doesn't mean questions on dping stuff in the container automatically become on-topic. Same goes for `adb` and Anbox, which is also a container *that isn't running Ubuntu*. And b ) OP did post on the Android SE, and we don't encourage people posting the same question on multiple sites. There's no reason to keep it open here now. (Now if adb weren't working correctly, that would be on-topic, being on the Ubuntu side.)

Comment: @muru For *(a)*, I don't follow. If this can be answered by explaining how to use `adb` in Ubuntu (`adb install something.apk`) then it is not analogous to actions performed *within a Debian container* where the use of SSH is incidental. I don't think you would actually consider a question about the syntax of the SSH command *itself* to be off-topic when the purpose is to run it on Ubuntu to access a non-Ubuntu system. *What am I missing?* For *(b)*, they did that after being told it was off-topic here. If the closure here was wrong originally, I think the other post's existence is irrelevant.

Comment: @EliahKagan that's a big if. OP already said they *installed* the APK, so they know how to install things. The problem is then that the installed things don't work correctly, for whatever reason. The question then isn't about SSH options, but doing something like `ssh foo apt install bar` and asking why `bar` isn't working correctly, which is not a problem for us. For b), I don't consider it irrelevant.

Comment: A solution is suggested here: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/anbox-how-to-install-google-play-store.html

Comment: Here is the guide to install Google Play Store in Anbox

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/07/anbox-how-to-install-google-play-store.html