# How can I install Play Store on Anbox on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android, anbox

How can I install Play Store and log in to my Play Store in Anbox? I'm looking for a tutorial. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anbox install problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944238/anbox-install-problem) Related question: [How to add Google Play support in Anbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904184/how-to-add-google-play-support-in-anbox)

Comment: I do not think Anbox supports google play store and even if if does games may not play. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/118903/what-android-emulators-are-available/955840#955840 . Genymotion is IMO the best option on Linux but it is not free and not fast. It emulates google play store, but it is not the exact same thing.